# Connecting to socket.io from pure js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Hi I looking for a documentation or example to connect to socket.io running on nodejs at server side from a pure JS from a client.

I have to remove the socket.io.js lib from the client side.

Comment: You cannot really connect to a remote framework without using the client side code...

Comment: Why do you have to remove the client side library file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.io provides various transport layers. If you are happy to experiment and are sure that your client supports WebSocket in all cases, then you might be successful in reproducing the WebSocket-based part of the socket.io protocol on the client side. This, however, seems to be a tedious task compared to just using the code that you would re-invent (partly) anyway.

**Use socket.io on the client side, or take an entirely different approach, also on the server side.**